# Is an Iterator to vec.end() still valid after vec.push_back() when there is no reallocation

Tags: c++, iterator

Is this example code valid?

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> vec(10); // create with 10 elements
  vec.reserve(100);    // set capacity to 100
  vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.end(); // points 1 past vec[9]

  vec.push_back( 777 );

  bool is_this_valid_and_true =  *iter == vec[10]; // ?

  // VS2010 runtime error in debug build:
  // Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable
  // Works in release build

  iter = vec.end() + 1; // points 2 past vec[10]?
  vec.push_back( 888 );
  vec.push_back( 999 );

  is_this_valid_and_true =  *iter == vec[12]; // ?
}
```

<strike>The error in VS2010 may be related to this [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557029/visual-c-iterator-debugging-incorrectly-raises-assertion-on-correct-use-of-return-value-of-std-vector-erase#details).</strike>

If I set the command line option `/D_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` or set

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
#include<vector>
```

there is no error.

**Edit:**

In light of the answers, I think this code should cause an error. There is no bug in the compiler. It only works in release mode because iterators are implemented as pointers.

Comment: <quote>there is no error.</quote> There is an error (its just silent and deadly and will kill you at a later point in time with flying nasal demons).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are thinking of iterators as pointers.

Iterators may use pointers as an implementation detail but they are not actual pointers.

Thus:

```
iter = vec.end() + 1; // This is not valid.
```

There is no such thing as two elements passed the end of data.

vec.end() returns an iterator that when decrement is a reference to the last elements (assuming there are elements). While an iterator referencing the last element when incremented is equivalent to the iterator returned by end().

```
// Note: Assuming vector iterators were not invalidated after an insert anyway.
//       But for arguments sake lets play this out.
//
vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.end(); // points 1 past vec[9]
vec.push_back( 777 );
bool is_this_valid_and_true =  *iter == vec[10]; // Not valid.
                                                 // This is the end() iterator
                                                 // de-referencing it is UB
```

But de-referenceing the iterator representing by end() is undefined behavior() (even if you have reserved space) (the implementation may not be using pointers. For example some of the DeBug STL implementations will do extensive error checking in the iterator code).

Comment: Thanks. So the trick `iter=vec.end(); iter--; vec_push_back(777); iter++;` would make `iter` a valid iterator to the now last element?

Comment: @JohnPS: As long as there's no reallocation, yes.

Comment: So, for debugging I guess the compiler marks an iterator as invalid whenever it is `== end()` during an insertion. Any modification or arithmetic afterward results in a debug error. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JohnPS: Personally I would not rely on it. But according to the (non canon) SGI documentation it should be good: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html (see point 5 at the bottom). As for how the debugging API work you will need to check the documentation for the STL.

Comment: Actually, it's a simple fix (I think). Just `push_back()` then set my iterator to `end()-1` afterward rather than setting it to `end()` then doing `push_back()`.

Answer (score 7):

23.2.4.3/1:

> Causes reallocation if the new size is
>   greater than the old capacity. If no
>   reallocation happens, all the
>   iterators and references **before**
>   the insertion point remain valid. If
>   an exception is thrown other than by
>   the copy constructor or assignment
>   operator of T there are no effects.

So no, `end()` doesn't have to be valid after `push_back`. The quote is in relation to `vector.insert`, `push_back` is defined in terms of `insert`

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the standard. I didn't know where to find the relevant info when I looked.