# Reallocation in std::vector after std::vector.reserve()

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a snippet of code where I first put some values in to a `std::vector` and then give an address of each of them to one of the objects that will be using them, like this:

```
std::vector < useSomeObject > uso;

// uso is filled

std::vector < someObject > obj;

for (int i=0; i < numberOfDesiredObjects; ++i){
    obj.push_back(someObject());
    obj.back().fillWithData();
}
for (int i=0; i < numberOfDesiredObjects; ++i){
    uso[i].setSomeObject(&obj[i]);
}

// use objects via uso vector
// deallocate everything
```

Now, since I'm sometimes a little bit of a style freak, I think this is *ugly* and would like to use only 1 for loop, kind of like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfDesiredObjects; ++i){
    obj.push_back(someObject());
    obj.back().fillWithData();
    uso[i].setSomeObject(&obj.back());
}
```

Of course, I can not do that because reallocation happens occasionally, and all the pointers I set became invalid.

So, **my question is:**
I  know that `std::vector.reserve()` is the way to go if you know how much you will need and want to allocate the memory in advance. If I make *sure* that I am trying to allocate enough memory in advance with `reserve()`, *does that guarantee that my pointers will stay valid?*

Thank you.

---

*Sidenote.* [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396634/is-an-iterator-to-vec-end-still-valid-after-vec-push-back-when-there-is-no-r) is a similar question, but there is not an answer to what I would like to know. Just to prevent it from popping up as a first comment to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I make sure that I am trying to allocate enough memory in advance with reserve(), does that guarantee that my pointers will stay valid?

Yes, it guarantees your pointers will stay valid unless:

- The *size* increases beyond the current *capacity* or
- Unless, you *erase* any elements, which you don't.

The iterator Invalidation rules for an vector are specified in **23.2.4.3/1** & **23.2.4.3/3** as:

> All iterators and references before the point of insertion are unaffected, unless the new container size is greater than the previous capacity (in which case all iterators and references are invalidated)
>
> Every iterator and reference after the point of erase is invalidated.

Answer (score 5):

This is, in fact, one of the principal reasons for using `reserve`.  You
are guaranteed that appending to the end of an `std::vector` will not
invalidate iterators, references or pointers to elements in the vector
as long as the new size of the vector does not exceed the old capacity.

Comment: I taught the principal reason was to try and avoid to many re-allocations. If that would be the reason, it would not do _too much_ damage if it didn't succeed and the re-allocation was still done. So, it is guaranteed that in case the `reserve()` fails, it will scream loudly and not just quietly continue with the prog. execution?

Comment: @penelope: If the new size is more than the current capacity(which is what reserve ensures to be up to your requirement) then relocation will occur.

Comment: @penelope The post-condition of `std::vector<>::reserve(n)` is `std::vector<>::capacity() >= n`.  If the new allocation fails, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @Als That's not the question.  The question is if the new size is less than or equal to the current capacity, are you guaranteed that reallocation will _not_ occur (and the answer is yes).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I just noticed my comment missed the crucial *only then* which i intended to specify that it will be the only scenario where reallocation can occur, that is what I answered in my answer too actually, but the mathematical quote of yours should make it aptly clear enough for the OP.

Comment: Just to be clear, the exception thrown will be usually an `std::bad_alloc`, considering `::new` is being used and not of any special exception type.Standard library containers rarely throw any exceptions of their own(`vector::at()` being the only i remember).They would usually only throw exceptions of standard library functionality's they use and which throw exceptions.

Comment: @Als It will be `std::bad_alloc`, or something derived from `std::bad_alloc`, if the standard allocator is used.  You raise a good question however: is it legal for my custom allocator to throw something entirely unrelated?  I don't know off hand.