# can a std::vector be modified within a range-based for() loop?

Tags: c++

Given this code:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto & i : v)
{
    if (foo(i))
    {
        v.push_back(bar());
    }
}
```

Am I correct in thinking this is undefined behaviour?

Is it only if the capacity needs to be increased that this causes a problem?  Meaning if I know beforehand the number of items to be added and call `reserve()` prior to the loop, then does this alleviate the "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: You've got it. Anything that changes the size, adding or removing, of the container ruins the book-keeping that's hidden inside the for loop.

Comment: it's also going to be confusing to anyone reading it later on, probably including yourself.   I'd wonder whether you intended the loop to be the original size, or the size including any new elements.  Code tricky enough that it needs a language lawyer is IMHO not maintainable code.

Comment: Had to delete my answer... and here I've lived with the idea that a cached `end` iterator was valid if one did `push_back` and there was no reallocation. :-( Possible dupe: [Is an Iterator to vec.end() still valid after vec.push_back() when there is no reallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396710/7582247)

Comment: cppreference says on interator invalidation upon push_back: "If the vector changed capacity, all of them. If not, only end()"  (see the respective section in this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector )

Comment: @kaba Yes, I had that in my now deleted answer - so the answer to OPs question is _Yes, it is undefined behavior_ and not _"it depends"_ as I wrote. :-P

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I would say, it depends, `foo(i)` might return `false` unconditionally (or `bar` throws or never returns) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, there's always that. :-) I'm thinking that _if_ one turned the iterators in a `vector` into guaranteed pointers (`&*begin()` and `&*std::prev(end()) + 1`) and used those it should be safe, right? It'd require a wrapper class to enable range-based `for` loops, but still.